# In javascript how do I centre text when I draw it to a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In javascript I can draw the text aligned to the left margin. I’m trying to align it to the canvas centre.

Canvas dimensions are read directly from a html canvas

```
    <canvas id="sketch" width=390 height=844></canvas>
```

and used to define a variable `centreX` representing the horizontal centre of the canvas.

```
    const cnv = document.getElementById('sketch');
    const ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
    const centreX = cnv.width / 2;
    const centreY = cnv.height / 2;
```

If the value of `state` is drawn to the canvas it appears left aligned

```
    let state = 1;

    function drawStateTextLeft(state) {
        const text = `${state + 1}`;
        ctx.fillText(`${state+1}`, 10, 30);                 // text appears
    }
```

I assume that drawing the same text aligned to the canvas centre is a simple matter of measuring the width of text and offsetting the text start by half the text width from the horizontal centre.

e.g.

```
    function drawStateTextCentre(state) {
        const text = `${state + 1}`;
        const textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;  // Calculate the width of the text
        var textX = centerX - textWidth / 2;                // Calculate the X position to center the text
//      alert(centreX + "\t" + textWidth + ”\t” + textX);                   
        ctx.fillText(text, textX, 30);                      // text does not appear
    }
```

The `alert` shows `centreX` is 195, `textWidth` is 13.3434 and `textX` is 181.656. However the text does not appear.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on the right track to center the text horizontally on the canvas. However, there is a small typo in your code. You are using ctxO to measure the text width, but you should be using ctx instead, which is your canvas 2D context.

```
function drawStateTextCentre(state) {
    const text = `${state + 1}`;
    const textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;  // Use ctx to measure text width
    const textX = centreX - textWidth / 2;         // Corrected variable name
    ctx.fillText(text, textX, 30);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. Unfortunately, the problem is unresolved.